# How to add Unix libraries to Visual Studio for Cross Compilation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unix, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile on Visual Studio and it just can't seem to find the Unix Libraries. I get the following errors:

```
cannot open source file "unistd.h"
cannot open source file "sys/socket.h"
cannot open source file "netinet/in.h"
cannot open source file "arpa/inet.h"
cannot open source file "netdb.h"
```

Either my google game is weak or there simply isn't an answer to getting VS to locate the Unix libraries.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Just to clarify, this is cross-compiling using WSL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, I personally know multiple project in the same setting (VS IDE + non-ms compiler).

As you are cross-compiling, you are using the VS IDE, but with a different compiler binary (which is probably `gcc` or maybe `llvm`).

The Visual Studio is mainly an IDE (integrated development environment), i.e. a GUI program to edit the source code and call the compiler. It has also the Microsoft's C compiler in it (as I can remember, it is called `vcc.exe`). It is a command line C compiler, i.e. it gets the sources, gets many header and library and compilation flags, and it produces object files from it.

The many, many options of the VS IDE is to configure and change the flags, with them the `vcc.exe` is called.

Of course, these flags are totally incompatible with any other compiler binary. For example, for the vcc you define headers with `/INCLUDE`, for gcc you use `-I` for the same task. You have no way to set these from the VS IDE.

But, you can add simple extra flags for it.

The VS has also its build mechanism, `nmake`, which is only partially compatible with the GNU Make (or with other builders). You can find the build command in the menu system (as I can remember, it is somewhere below "options"), you can use a GNU Make from Cygwin or even an [Ubuntu bash](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) and call this as build command.

Comment: Thank you. My issue was that I created a project in visual studio for linux cross compilation but I already had code written in another file. I would open it in the project but I never added it to the solution explorer. So I'm guessing that it wasn't considered to be apart of the "linux cross-compilation family." I just added it, built it, and debugged it, and it worked beautifully. The answer is always something simple eh?

Comment: @Dave Also I thanks :-) Well, last time I used MSVS, I didn't find this linux cross-compilation feature. But it is nice to hear :-)